# How to get an id and foreign id from multiple csv files

Tags: java, java-8, java-11

Hi I am trying to get user `id` column and `foreign_id` column from multiple csv files.  After it loops (`if (userAId.equals(userBId))`) it doesn't find the match of id ... I have tried the below code before and no luck.  Any good suggestions?

```
public List<User> getObjectFiles(List<Map<String, String>>> csvFiles) {

  List<User> user = new ArrayList<>();
  List<Map<String, String>> userARows = csvFiles.get("userARows");
  List<Map<String, String>> userBRows = csvFiles.get("userBRows");

  List<String> userAId = new ArrayList<>();
  for (Map<String, String> userARow: userARows) {
    userAId = userARow.entry.stream()
              .filter(key->key.getKey().equals("id")
              .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }

  List<String> userBId = new ArrayList<>();
  for (Map<String, String> userBRow: userBRows) {
    userBId = userBRow.entry.stream()
              .filter(key->key.getKey().equals("foreign_id")
              .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
  if (userAId.equals(userBId)) {
  //....more code to add for List<User> user
  }

  return user;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically its not clear what you're asking here.

Reviewing the attached code:

The content of the loop, where you stream over map is strange:

***You iterate over all the entries of the map instead of using a simple "get" and in addition you always rewrite the value instead of accumulating it***.

Why not just:

```
List<String> userAId = new ArrayList<>();
for (Map<String, String> userARow: userARows) {
    String userId = userARow.get("id");
    userAIDs.add(userId);
}
```

This in turn could be rewritten as a stream:

```
List<String> userAIds = userARows
                        .stream()
                        .map(row -> row.get("id"))
                        .collect(Collectors.asList());
```

The code for User B looks exactly the same, actually you could even extract that into a private method to avoid the same code duplication, but its subjective:

```
private List<String> calculateByFieldName(List<Map<String, String>> content, String fieldName) {
 return content.stream()
               .map(row -> row.get(fieldName))
               .collect(Collectors.asList());
}

// Then your code becomes:


public List<User> getObjectFiles(List<Map<String, String>>> csvFiles) {

  List<User> user = new ArrayList<>();
  List<Map<String, String>> userARows = csvFiles.get("userARows");
  List<Map<String, String>> userBRows = csvFiles.get("userBRows");

  List<String> userAId = calculateByFieldName(userARows, "id");
  List<String> userBId = calculateByFieldName(userBRows, "foreign_id");

  if (userAId.equals(userBId)) {
  //....more code to add for List<User> user
  }

  return user;
}
```

Anyways, its not clear what do you mean by "the search stops" - obviously if the lists are not equals (have the same content and order of elements) the program won't enter the "if" condition and you'll get to the last line.

Comment: Thank you @Mark Bramnik, I will try your suggestion. I meant to say that when it loops it doesnt find the ones that do match with its values. Yes it doesn't enter that if statement for those that don't match.  I will make that explanation better.  I thought through this too much with maps...